# How to prevent browsers from remembering last logged user?

Tags: browser, browser-cache, autofill

Let me start off with these sources I have found that are not helpful to me, because they are not asking the same thing, no matter how similar it might sound:

- [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)
- [Disable form autofill in Chrome without disabling autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938891/disable-autofill-in-chrome-without-disabling-autocomplete)
- [Google Chrome form autofill and its yellow background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920306/google-chrome-form-autofill-and-its-yellow-background)
- [How do I stop Chrome from pre-populating input boxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999578/how-do-i-stop-chrome-from-pre-populating-input-boxes?lq=1)
  And recently:
- [Should autocomplete="off" be used for all sensitive fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040731/should-autocomplete-off-be-used-for-all-sensitive-fields)

Essentially, these threads all suggest browser settings & adding the attribute autocomplete='off'. This is not a valid solution for me nor is it the issue that I am having. My issue is as follows:

Using Incognito Mode in Chrome:

1. User A clicks on "Patient Portal" to bring them to the login page. (Good)
2. User A logs into their account by filling in their email & password. (Good)
3. User A logs out of their account & is brought back to the Kiosk home page. (Good)
4. User B clicks on "Patient Portal" to bring them to the login page. (Good)
5. User B sees User A's email filled in the email field. (BAD)

User B can remove User A's email from the field & enter their own without Chrome's suggestions of previously entered emails.

It is not okay to retain a users email address on a public computer, how might I fix this issue?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3040731

Comment: @RobertHarvey Please read my entire question. This solution does not work for me because it is NOT the same question.

Comment: Then what is your actual question?  You're going to have to be more specific if you want to differentiate your question from the one I linked.

Comment: I don't know how to make it any more clear than the step by step explaination I just explained. It is not autocomplete that is the issue (as I have previously explained), but rather after the user has logged out, gone away from the page, & returned that is the issue. Read the question to complete understanding.

Comment: If it's not autocomplete that's causing this, then what mechanism is?  Do you need to dump the cache?

Comment: I don't know, that is why I'm asking the question. THis is being ran in Incognito mode, there is no caching.

Comment: Despite your protestations, I think it might really be autocomplete that is causing this.  Also, rolling back a moderator's edit is a really bad idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67253/discussion-between-crystal-miller-and-robert-harvey). I do not believe that you fully understand my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another developer was dynamically adding in the last logged email into the email field in a php file I did not have access to.
-_-